# How to use view to display a list of nodes?

Tags: views

My site have a restaurant node type and each restaurant node has multiple menu items. Each menu item has food name, price , discount, etc.

What I want to do is creating a view that shows a list of all menu item node list which belong to a specific restaurant node.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: How are the food menu items saved in Drupal?  Are they nodes?

Comment: Yeah, both them are node

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes.  I think you can do this via relations in views

Comment: How are you showing the restaurant node type?  Are you using a node template for that?

Answer (score 0):

Install

[Menu Node API](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node)

> Manages relationships between node ids and menu items.

and [Menu Node Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_node_views)

> The Menu Node Views module provides Views integration for nodes
>   assigned to the menu system.

Create a view something like this:

View of Content (nodes)

**Contextual filter:**

1. Add a contextual filter of Content: Nid

**Fields:**

1. Content: Title, and exclude from display.
2. Menu: Link title (The link text used for the menu item.)

**Format:** Unformatted list, with settings of Grouping field Nr.1 -> Content:title

That should do it.

This is not the only module solution available so research others as well.

Comment: Sorry, the menu in my question is the menu containing food name, price, discount. etc. Not the menu in Drupal navigation area. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a function called *views_embed_view*.

1) Create an *embed*-type view display to display menu items. Assign a *contextual filter* for this view to be the referenced node (i.e. the id of the restaurant node).

2) Using a custom block that is shown only on restaurants' nodes, put these lines of PHP code (using PHP filter):

```
<?php
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
 $nid = $node->nid;
}

print views_embed_view('view-name', 'views-display-name', $nid);
?>
```

That's it.